# VBS - создание BAT-файла

Tags: bat, vbscript

Здравствуйте. Необходимо при помощи VBS скрипта создать BAT. У меня есть скрипт:

```
Dim FSO
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim file
Set file = FSO.CreateTextFile("c:\windows\system32\drivers\$130.bat", true)
Set file = FSO.OpenTextFile("c:\windows\system32\drivers\$130.bat", 2, True)
file.Write "Скрипт bat'ника"
file.Close
```

Однако, возникла проблема. При выполнении VBS скрипта возникает ошибка, о которой сообщает WINDOWS - в каждой из строк в конце не хватает символов.
Без переносов в BAT не обойтись, иначе работать не будет. Что мне делать, чтобы VBS нормально реагировал на переносы? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо использовать метод `WriteLine` вместо `Write`. Вторая ошибка - вызов `OpenTextFile` не нужен. Попробуйте такой код:

```
Dim FSO, MyFile
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFile = FSO.CreateTextFile("c:\windows\system32\drivers\$130.bat", True)
MyFile.WriteLine("Скрипт bat'ника")
MyFile.Close
```

Comment: Спасибо, я уже понял.

Comment: Помогите, пожалуйста с этим вопросом, если можете - [вопрос >](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647474/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-vbs-%D0%B8%D0%B7-vbs)