# Создание VBS из VBS

Tags: windows, bat, vbscript

Здравствуйте.

Недавно появилась необходимость создать VBS файл из VBS. VBS без проблем создаёт BAT файлы, однако с VBS у него проблемы. Подскажите, что делать? Предполагаю, что проблема в скобках, стоящих перед путём в 5-ой строке, но если их убрать, скрипт работать не будет. Заранее спасибо!

```
Dim FSO, file
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = FSO.CreateTextFile("c:\windows\system32\drivers\$130.vbs", true)
file.WriteLine ("Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")")
file.WriteLine ("Return = WshShell.Run("c:\windows\system32\$130_archiver.bat", 0, true)")
file.Close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Синтаксис. Кавычки внутри символьной строки - двойные кавычки.

```
Dim FSO, file
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = FSO.CreateTextFile("c:\windows\system32\drivers\$130.vbs", True)
file.WriteLine ("Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"")")
file.WriteLine ("Return = WshShell.Run(""c:\windows\system32\$130_archiver.bat"", 0, true)")
file.Close
```